# C++ 2d static array and memory allocation

Tags: c++

I think, I have just made a mistake: I was allocating a static 2D array and accessing it as 1 dimension.

Could you tell me how bad it is - method *geta*?

The code below works fine on my Windows, and Linux: *actual* is always eqauls to *expected* and *stride* is always equals to *N*.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define N 2000

int a[N][N];

int geta(int i, int j) {
    return *(a[0] + i * N + j);
}


int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int const expected = a[i][j];
            int const actual = geta(i, j);
            if (actual != expected) {
                printf("wrong data at [%d,%d] expected=%d actual=%d", i, j, expected, actual);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        int stride = a[N] - a[N - 1];
        if (stride != N) {
            printf("wrong: i=%d c=%d N=%d", i, stride, N);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for improvement of already working code you should better ask that question at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: `geta` has undefined behaviour. `a[0]` is an array of N elements, adding anything larger than N to it goes over array bounds. Style-wise, it's all extremely bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you tell me how bad it is - method `geta`?

Bad. But correct. `C++` guarantees memory for `a` to be contiguous and the memory layout to be row major, so your code returns in a correct manner the expected element. Let's see how:

The type of `a[0]` is `int[2000]` <sup>1)</sup> . But as soon as you do arithmetic on it it decays, i.e. `int*`. So `+i*N` moves the pointer to the (beginning of the) line `i` and `+j` moves the pointer to the column `j`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> actually it's `int(&)[2000]` but not that relevant here

Comment: I said it's bad because this code wouldn't pass any code review. If you seek improvements you could post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Be sure to check their help pages to make it an on-topic question there.

Comment: Thanks. It is logic, that c++ allocate memory for 2D array contiguous. But I did not expect it to be a standard.

Comment: @AntoniJakubiak You are welcome. Consider to mark the  answer as accepted if you feel it answered your question.